# SVG path position incorrect on safari

Tags: jquery, svg

i am using jQuery's `offset()` to return the position of a path element in a resized svg element.  This is working fine in all browsers except for safari which return's (i presume) the offset related to the unscaled SVG. I have tried using `getBBox` but the values are incorrect.

```
$('body').append('<div style="position:absolute">Pos:'+ $('#path4108').offset()+'</div>');
```

Any ideas how I can retrieve the correct position?

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7q2j6Le/1/)

Comment: You should avoid using jQuery to work with SVG elements. jQuery is only designed to work with HTML elements, and with a few exceptions doesn't support SVG elements.